# Draw mouse cursor

Tags: winapi, gdi, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to simulate a mouse cursor in Win32 forms. On every `WM_MOUSEMOVE` I have

```
hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
////Get device context
hDeviceContext = GetDC(hwnd);
hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDeviceContext);
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCMem, 50, 50);
hbmOld = SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);
DrawIcon(hDCMem, x, y, hCursor);
SelectObject(hDCMem, hbmOld);
```

But I don't see anything being drawn. However if I drew directly on the DC:

```
DrawIcon(hDeviceContext, x, y, hCursor);
```

I do see the cursor but it does not erase the image as I move the cursor, leaving a long tail behind.

Comment: Curious, why are you trying to simulate a cursor instead of just letting Windows draw it for you?

Comment: I'm working on an experimental app where i'm using a high-def mouse. I'd like to set the mouse to a high reporting dpi, say 5000, but get the same on screen response as a normal mouse at 400 dpi.

Comment: interesting, I've added an answer with an alternate approach that might be worth considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't paint in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, that's what `WM_PAINT` is for. Basically, you need to handle three messages:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        cWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXCURSOR); // saving the cursor dimensions
        cHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCURSOR);
    break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        rcOld = rcNew;
        rcNew.left   = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);     // saving the mouse coordinates
        rcNew.top    = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
        rcNew.right  = rcNew.left + cWidth;
        rcNew.bottom = rcNew.top + cHeight;
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rcOld, TRUE);      // asking to redraw the rectangles
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rcNew, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        DrawIcon(hDC, rcNew.left, rcNew.top, hCursor);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
```

Note: I'm not sure what do you mean by "simulating a mouse cursor", but there could be a better way of doing what you probably want. Please check functions [`SetCursor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393.aspx) and [`SetWindowLongPtr() with GCL_HCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx).

Comment: Redrawing the entire client area is probably inefficient; much better to remember the cursor rectangle each time you draw it, and just invalidate the old and new rectangles on mouse movement. It's also possible to get multiple WM_MOUSEMOVE messages before a WM_PAINT is generated so for responsiveness you probably want to put an UpdateWindow() in there as well.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Thanks, both your points are correct. I have edited my answer.

Comment: What's the difference between DrawIcon and moving the cursor to a device context buffer and use BitBlt to draw to the screen?

Comment: @dave, I can't say about the Microsoft one, but the Wine implementation of `DrawIconEx` uses `StretchBlt` internally: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/cursoricon.c#L2212

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth:

Another approach that might be worth looking at is to use a WS_EX_TOPMOST|[WS_EX_LAYERED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) window that you move around as needed, and let Windows handle the drawing/transparency for you. This has the advantage that it won't interfere at all with the drawing main window, and will work even if the main window has child controls or similar.

It will also allow your 'mouse pointer' to 'hang over the edge' of your window - eg. when when mouse is positioned to point at the extreme bottom-right pixel, the tail and arrow of a regular mouse pointer will be over the frame and other windows behind it, and you can't do this just by drawing your own window's client area.

--

Having said that, I'm not sure that 'faking' the mouse position is the proper thing to do here, though it may well get you up and running. Another approach is to let the mouse behave as normal, but for apps that require the higher resolution, have another API that exposes the more exact values. Along with the usual mouse/keyboard messages and APIs, windows also has various techniques and APIs  (eg [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543(v=vs.85))) for getting input information, defining additional input devices, and I think also associating additional information with messages, and one of those techniques might be more appropriate here. It might be worthwhile to re-ask your question, but focus on the higher-level on, not the cursor drawing.

Comment: RAW INPUT is exactly what I currently use. RAW INPUT reports mouse movements exactly as seen by the device driver. The problem though is that with a high-res mouse, the on screen cursor will fly so quickly to the edges that it is nearly impossible to point. So essentially I want to "downsample" the on screen cursor movement (to that of a normal 400dpi mouse) while retaining the physical spatial resolution at 5000dpi. The other option is to write a mouse driver to do the downsampling. The easier thing appears to be simulating the cursor in the application at a lower res.

Comment: Re the fast pointer problem - what about then changing the pointer speed in the Mouse control panel, will it go slow enough? That way you have usable pointer speed (Windows downsamples for you), but still get the high-res samples via raw input for your app.

Comment: That worked. I actually tried the option before but didn't get it working last time -- the problem was setting the speed option in the mouse specific driver, namely logitech. Turns out that you need to set mouse speed using the windows native driver for RAW INPUT to receive unfiltered inputs.